# How do I reset the game object movement after I setActive the object to false? (ObjectPool problem)

Tags: unity, c#

This is all from objectpooling. Instead of deleting it, it said to set the gameobject to false. The problem is, it didn't reset when it came back SetActive(true). What should I do?

this is the script of that object

```
    public class ObjectMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] int PositionIndex;
    float TimeLeft;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        TimeLeft = Random.Range(2, 6);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        MovingIn();
    }

    void MovingIn()
    {
        TimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        switch (PositionIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                if (TimeLeft <= 0)
                {
                    TimeLeft = Random.Range(1, 3);
                    PositionIndex = 2;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                transform.Translate(Vector2.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                if (TimeLeft <= 0)
                {
                    TimeLeft = Random.Range(0.2f, 1);
                    PositionIndex = Random.Range(3, 5);
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                break;
            case 4:
                transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                break;

        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("wall"))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the script from objectpool

```
public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject prefab;
    [SerializeField] int poolsize = 10;

    List<GameObject> _pool;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _pool = new List<GameObject>();
        CreatePooler();
    }

    void CreatePooler()  //Add in to "CreateInstance" to store the prefab
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < poolsize; i++)
        {
            _pool.Add(CreateInstance());
        }
    }

    GameObject CreateInstance()   //Store it. Only to be activated (setActive, true) when needed
    {
        GameObject newInstance = Instantiate(prefab);
        newInstance.SetActive(false);
        return newInstance;
    }

    public GameObject GetInstanceFromPool()  
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _pool.Count; i++)  //if prefab not being used (setActive / active in the hierachy), returning inactive object
        {
            if (!_pool[i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                return _pool[i];
            }
        }

        return CreateInstance(); //So if being used, will store in CreateInstance
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already reset the TimeLeft variable in OnEnable() — what other state do you want to reset? Have you tried resetting it in OnEnable() in a similar way? How does the behaviour differ from what you want?

Comment: Reset the one on Update()

Comment: I'm afraid that message does not clarify anything for me. Do you perhaps mean you want to reset the value of PositionIndex, which controls the behaviour of the method you call in Update?

Comment: Typically, you clear old state in `OnDisable()` (if necessary) and set up new state in `OnEnable()`